# Why does touch $(ls).bla create only one file

Tags: linux

Well in one directory I have 24 files but when I run the above command it makes only one file, but if i type echo $(ls) it lists all files

Comment: Try `echo $(ls).bla`

Comment: You should read more about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (see also [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) ...) and [bash shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Guess, you mixed up the file expansion. Try this:

```
echo $(ls *.bla)
touch $(ls *.bla)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what is happening when running `$ touch "$(ls).bla"` in a folder containing a single file `foo` that illustrates what is happening:

```
$ ls
 foo

$ touch "$(ls).bla"

$ ls
 foo  foo.bla

$ touch "$(ls).bla"

$ ls
 foo  'foo'$'\n''foo.bla.bla'   foo.bla
```

As you can see the first time the `touch` command is called it creates a single file named `foo.bla`. When creating a subshell with `$(ls)` as the argument the `touch` command will get that as a single command line parameter not multiple ones. That is why the second  time `touch "$(ls).bla"` is run above the result yields a single file with a strange filename.

What you probably want if you want to create empty files with the same name as other files in a folder is to pipe the output of `ls` to `xargs` like this:

```
$ ls | xargs -i touch "{}.bla"
```

The -i flag to `xargs` causes it to replace `{}` with the file names it gets from `ls`.